# I keep getting a syntax error python-3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I keep Getting a syntax error on line 32, please help.
I inserted a User-Agent and it keeps rejecting it

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')

print(x.read())

url = 'http://pythonprogramming.net'
values = {'s':'basic',
      'submit':'search'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

print(respData)

try:
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/search?q=test')

    print(x.read())

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

try:
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test'
#In line 32 i keep getting a syntax error
    headers = {}
```

I get a syntax error here
        headers = ['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)
    AppleWebkit/537 
       (KHTML, like Geko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respData =resp.read()

```
    saveFile = open('withHeaders.txt','w')
    saveFile.write(str(respData))
    saveFile.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```